# textField.getText() not working when textField is in a different panel (compare to the button.addActionListener)

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java Swing and encountered an issue when using `JTextField.getText()`. Basically .getText() is not picking up whatever string I put into the text field and returns an empty string.

I think the reason I got an empty string is that the JTextField is in a different panel than the button, but don't know how to get it working... Any help will be highly appreciated!

Here is my logic

> (1) Create a JFrame, call it frame
>
> (2) Create several JPanels and frame.add(JPanel)
>
> (3) Fill in the panels with JButton and JTextField. Note that the text field is in a different panel than the button.
>
> (4) Call button.addActionListener(...) and use JTextField.getText()

Here is my code:

```
package GUI;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class aaaaa {

// Class attributes
// Overall class attributes
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simulation App");
    
// Class attributes for method setTextFieldPar
private JPanel panelThetaCh = new JPanel();
private JPanel panelSetButton = new JPanel();

private JTextField textFieldThetaCh = new JTextField();

private String StringThetaCh;

// Class attributes for method setButton
private JButton buttonSetPar;

// ========================================================================================================================
// Class methods

// Text field of all simulation parameters
public void setTextFieldPar(JPanel panel, JTextField textField, String latexString){
    // Panel layout - FlowLayout
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    
    JLabel labelText = new JLabel("text");
    panel.add(labelText);
    
    // Create text field        
    textField = new JTextField(13);
    panel.add(textField);
}


// Button "Set Parameters"
public void setButton (JPanel panel){
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0));
    panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    
    buttonSetPar = new JButton("Set Parameters");
    panel.add(buttonSetPar);        
}   


// Monitor input in text field
public void monitorTextField() {
    buttonSetPar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            // Extract numbers entered in text field for the parameters
            StringThetaCh = textFieldThetaCh.getText();
                
            if (StringThetaCh.equals("")) {
                JFrame errorWindow = new JFrame("Error");
                errorWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                errorWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorWindow, "At least one text field is empty, please enter numerical values");
            }
        }
    });
}


// Constructor
public aaaaa(){
    frame.setSize(350, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    
    // Text field for parameters
    setTextFieldPar(panelThetaCh, textFieldThetaCh, "\\theta_{CH}");

    // Button for set parameter
    setButton(panelSetButton);
    
    // Monitoring input in text field
    monitorTextField();
    
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {    
        public void run() {    
            aaaaa window2 = new aaaaa();
            window2.frame.setVisible(true);
        } 
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already creating the text field in the class declaration:

```
private JTextField textFieldThetaCh = new JTextField();
```

then you pass it to the method `setTextFieldPar` and in there you are creating another text field that is added to the panel:

```
textField = new JTextField(13);
panel.add(textField);
```

So, the class variable `textFieldThetaCh` is not the one added to the panel and therefore is inaccessible to the user.

Simply remove the creation of the new text field in `setTextFieldPar` and it will work.

Here is a visual representation of what is happening:

1. in the class declaration:

[image: class declaration]

2. inside the `setTextFieldPar` method (remember that the parameters are passed by value, so a copy of the object reference is made):

[image: setTextFieldPar method]

3. after `textField = new JTextField(13);`, the copy of the reference now points to a new object:

[image: after textField = new JTextField(13)]

4. after `panel.add(textField);`, the new object is added to the panel, which is not what `textFieldThetaCh` is pointing to:

[image: after `panel.add(textField)]

Comment: Excellent answer Loris! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

i just use textFieldThetaCh directly without send it as pram 
you was taking the text from textFieldThetaCh when you are typing the text on textField

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class aaaaa {

// Class attributes
// Overall class attributes
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simulation App");

// Class attributes for method setTextFieldPar
private JPanel panelThetaCh = new JPanel();
private JPanel panelSetButton = new JPanel();

private JTextField textFieldThetaCh = new JTextField(13);

private String StringThetaCh;

// Class attributes for method setButton
private JButton buttonSetPar;



// Text field of all simulation parameters
public void setTextFieldPar(JPanel panel, JTextField textField, String         
latexString){
// Panel layout - FlowLayout
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
frame.add(panel);
panel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

JLabel labelText = new JLabel("text");
panel.add(labelText);

// Create text field
// textField = new JTextField(13);

panel.add(textFieldThetaCh);
}


// Button "Set Parameters"
public void setButton (JPanel panel){
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0));
panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
frame.add(panel);
panel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

buttonSetPar = new JButton("Set Parameters");
panel.add(buttonSetPar);
}


// Monitor input in text field
public void monitorTextField() {
buttonSetPar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        // Extract numbers entered in text field for the parameters
        StringThetaCh = textFieldThetaCh.getText();

        if (StringThetaCh.equals("")) {
            JFrame errorWindow = new JFrame("Error");
            errorWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            errorWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorWindow, "At least one text 
field is empty, please enter numerical values");
        }
        else
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
StringThetaCh);

    }
});
}


// Constructor
public aaaaa(){
frame.setSize(350, 800);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

// Text field for parameters
setTextFieldPar(panelThetaCh, textFieldThetaCh, "\\theta_{CH}");

// Button for set parameter
setButton(panelSetButton);

// Monitoring input in text field
monitorTextField();

}


public static void main(String args[]) {
 EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        aaaaa window2 = new aaaaa();
        window2.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your button actionPerformed is within monitorTextField() which is in the constructor. This gets fired up at the beginning but never called upon afterwards (referring to monitorTextField()).
Put the actionPerformed somewhere outside of a function so it can function anytime the button is pressed and it should work.